# Cant select from my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access a password that is crypted on my databse bu i get this error all the time and i dont know how to fix it, i am pritty new to php so :P

Here is the error message: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\BSP\login.php on line 18

any help is thanked for! :)

PHP code:

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    session_start();

    function cryptPsw($input, $rounds = 9) {
        $salt = "";
        $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));

        for($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) {
            $salt .= $saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)];
        }
        return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $rounds) .$salt);
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $uname = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT ´username´ FROM ´users´ WHERE ´username´ = "$username"');

    if(mysqli_num_rows($uname) == 0) {
        echo '<script>console.log("Username not found!")</script>';
    }
    else {
        $psw = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT ´password´ FROM ´users´ WHERE ´username´ = "$username"');
        $hashedPsw = cryptPsw($psw);
        if(crypt($password, $hashedPsw) == $hashedPsw) {
            echo '<script>console.log("You are now logged in")</script>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<script>console.log("Wrong password, try again!")</script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

The html form:

```
<div class="login-form">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>

        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
            <label for="checkbox">Remember</label>
        </span>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And btw, i am using blowfish algorithms

Comment: Your ticks go the wrong way

Comment: And you can view the site ower here: http://simpolarna.sytes.net/

Comment: Strawberry has it - you're using incorrect quoting your field names. they should be backticks: \`, not `´` like you're using. If you had even BARE MINIMUM error handling on your queries, instead of blindly assuming success, you'd have seen the mysql error messages.

Comment: or omitted altogether!

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: the ´ sign does nothing, it only makes it easier to read..

Answer (score 0):

Try using as below i.e remove front tick `´` use **backticks** or leave it as it is, if you have used any reserved word/s or keyword/s, in that case you can use **backticks**

```
'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = "$username" '
```

instead of

```
'SELECT ´username´ FROM ´users´ WHERE ´username´ = "$username"'
```